# Can't write to my Windows partitions?

Tags: partitioning, mount, 20.04

My Windows disk partitions are appearing under “Other Locations”, When I access the partitions, I can open files, read them, but I cannot create a new folder.
I'm using dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Were they mounted as RW?  (read-write).  If the *file-system* is unclean (ie. not all data has been written to the partition cleanly such as fast-boot enabled or a hibernated windows 10) a *file-system* will only open RO (read-only) to prevent data-loss.  If a *fs* flips from RW to RO, it's because errors were detected, and flipping to RO prevents data loss. You'll need to provide more detail (or check logs, details when mounted are the best clue as to reason why it's mounted RO; though it could be other permissions issue too).

Comment: So should i disable the fast boot in windows 10? will i be able to acheive what i want now?

Comment: if that's the only reason you can't open the *fs* RO, then yes.

Comment: I followed a guide in which i had to first note down a number from sudo blkid of my ntfs drives and then i had to open a file /etc/fstab and write some texts in the end of the file to mount it. I also did what guiverc said. so one of those two things worked. Thanks by the way :)